# Unable to lock entry:

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

`Entry` was automatically empty once I moved to another page. How do I maintain the state of Entry so that it will only change/empty when I want?

page1.xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="NSF_app.setting">
  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="20"
    VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
    <Entry x:Name="UserEntry"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    InputTransparent="True" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Button Text="read_Only" Clicked="Reado_OnClicked"/>
    <Button Text="Remove" Clicked="remove_OnClicked"/>
  </StackLayout>
```

page1.xaml.cs:

```cs
namespace NSF_app
{
    public partial class page1
    {
        public static string EntryValue = "";
        public page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Reado_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserEntry.IsReadOnly = true;
            UserEntry.InputTransparent = true;
            UserEntry.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void remove_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserEntry.IsReadOnly = false;
            UserEntry.InputTransparent = false;
            UserEntry.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test with the code below. The entry is enabled at first time and then i click the remove to input the text "hello". After that i would navigate to another page. When i click the back button to back to the Page1, the "hello" text would still in the entry.

App.xaml.cs:

```
  public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
    }
```

Page1.xaml.cs:

```
 public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static string EntryValue = "";
    private void Reado_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserEntry.IsReadOnly = true;
        UserEntry.InputTransparent = true;
        UserEntry.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void remove_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserEntry.IsReadOnly = false;
        UserEntry.InputTransparent = false;
        UserEntry.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
```

**Updated:**

A easy way is two define the property in your AppShell.

AppShell.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public ICommand LogoutCommand => new Command(async () => await NavigationEvent());
    public string EntryValue { get; set; }
    async Task NavigationEvent()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("page1");
    }

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute("page1", typeof(Page1));
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
        Padding="20"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Entry
            x:Name="UserEntry"
            InputTransparent="True"
            IsEnabled="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="{Binding EntryValue}"
            TextChanged="UserEntry_TextChanged"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Clicked="Reado_OnClicked" Text="read_Only" />
        <Button Clicked="remove_OnClicked" Text="Remove" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
  public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserEntry.Text = new AppShell().EntryValue;
    }

    private void Reado_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserEntry.IsReadOnly = true;
        UserEntry.InputTransparent = true;
        UserEntry.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void remove_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserEntry.IsReadOnly = false;
        UserEntry.InputTransparent = false;
        UserEntry.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void UserEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        new AppShell().EntryValue = UserEntry.Text;
    }
```

Comment: You could check the screenshot: https://imgur.com/CUovugV

Comment: The Idea was great but, navigate using navigation.push async will affect my required output. my concept is here - https://imgur.com/a/O2awoJa - when I use back button the lable was emptied.

Comment: ohhh, you used the shell menu item? I would check it again and feedback ASAP.

Comment: @BalaVelan I have updated the reply. You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/xt1e5mb

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ciTObQo  - If exit from the app and open the app, that entry again emptied. Is it posible to make the entry lock ,even we exit from the app.

Comment: If you want to save the data when you close the app, you could save it in the database or file in the device. When you open the app, load the data again.

Comment: You could check the sample code for the sqlite database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todo/